# react element is hidden even with z-index of 9999

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on a jsfiddle react sidebar project, and have it so the sidebar can expand/collapse dynamically based on how much screen size you have.
I want the button for sidebar expand/collapse to always be visible though, so I added it to my sidebar and gave the element a left:xxxpx attribute, but the "CLICKME!" button to expand/collapse the sidebar is always hidden under the main content, even after I've added `z-index:99999!important` to try and make sure the button is always visible

in css my element has these attributes:

```
/* Style the `label` that we use to target the `.sidebar-checkbox` */
.sidebar-toggle {
    left:230px;
    z-index:999999!important;
    
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.65rem;
  color: #505050;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

But the button remains partially hidden under the main content, is there any way I can make this "CLICKME!" button always on top of the main content?

https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/04tryqwk/14/

Comment: It’s not hidden under the main content; it’s contained within the sidebar, which is only so wide and declares `overflow-y: auto` (i.e. horizontal overflow is hidden).

Comment: @Ry- but removing `overflow-y` causes the button to still disapear when clicked?

Comment: After removing `overflow-y: auto`, I don’t see the button disappear when clicked. You probably shouldn’t remove the ability to scroll the menu, though; what if the menu is too tall for the user’s viewport? They can’t scroll the overall page to access the bottom of a `position: fixed` element.

Comment: z-index is no magic tool that moves things to the front. An element with z-index 1 can be on top of one with z-index 10. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/#:~:text=The%20z-index%20property%20determines,to%20the%20display%2C%20or%20viewport.

Comment: while removing overflow-y from my jsfiddle works, if i do the same thing on my locally running desktop app, it does not fix the error. Ive tried recreating my code as a code sanbox.io thing, but that looked very broken. maybe my react version isnt matching jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
.sidebar-toggle {    
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.65rem;
  color: #505050;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Above css takes care of the *partially hidden* issue.

[image]